# How to convert a dataframe to json and saving it using tkinter GUI

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, tkinter

I am writing a GUI app that loads a csv file, cleans it and then saves it as a JSON file dump in same directory...I am stuck please help...I have created two buttons one to handle the loading of the file and another to write JSON, I know I can use one button to achieve this, but don't know how to save the file so it appears in the same directory as the csv file.
my program so far:

```
def load_frequency_data():
global df, df_rows
file_path = label_file['text']

try:
    csv_filename = r'{}'.format(file_path)
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_filename, delimiter=',')
    df.rename(columns={'airport_ident': 'ident'}, inplace=True)
    df = df[['ident', 'frequency_mhz']]

    clear_frequency_data()

    my_tree['columns'] = list(df.columns)
    my_tree['show'] = 'headings'
    for column in my_tree['columns']:
        my_tree.heading(column, text=column)

        df_rows = df.to_numpy().tolist()

    for row in df_rows:
        my_tree.insert('', 'end', values=row)
    return None

except ValueError:
    tkinter.messagebox.showerror('Information', 'File is invalid')
    return None
except FileNotFoundError:
    tkinter.messagebox.showerror('Information', "File not found")
```

my second button code:

```
def save_tojson():
if messagebox.askyesno('Confirmation', 'Are you sure you want to save data as json file?'):
    data = df.to_json(orient='split', indent=3)
```

I am trying to use the converted csv file (df) to save as a JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `path_or_buf` argument of [`pandas.DataFrame.to_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) to determine the exported path:

```py
from pathlib import Path


def save_tojson():
    file_path = Path(label_file['text'])

    if messagebox.askyesno('Confirmation', 'Are you sure you want to save data as json file?'):
        df.to_json(file_path.with_suffix('.csv'), orient='split', indent=3)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now I get an error saying name df is not defined...more help needed pls

Comment: @PlumChy Return the modified dataframe in `load_frequency_data`, then pass it to `save_tojson` method.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean, by writing the syntax, i am getting things muddled up....

Comment: @PlumChy Have no idea how you call these two functions. The idea is to let `save_tojson` know the modified dataframe.